# How to prevent mywebapplication to specific network/Ip?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have a web application in Azure and it's accessible over the Internet.

I want to restrict the access to public and allow the specific Network/IP.

I have configured **Inbound** rule and **Outbound** rule in **NSG** for blocking access to specific network, but still my webapplication is accessible over the Internet(AnyNetwork).

**Outbound Rule:**

Source IP: Vnet
Port:Any
Destination: Web application
Port: Any

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about Azure App Service, follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?tabs=azurecli) to set up access restrictions.